# How to extract specific number of characters from a substring in python with same suffix

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, substring

I have this python code to extract the image `src` from an HTML website

```
listingid=[img['src'] for img in soup.select('[src]')]
```

Now would like to extract the values from the following output and store into a dictionary:

Any approach I can take to achieve this?

Im thinking if there is any syntax in python to take 14 characters before a specific suffix(like .jpg)

Comment: `s[-18:-4]`? Python slices can take negative indices to mean start from the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative indices in Python slices to count from the end. Since you say in the question you want 14 characters before a 4 character suffix, a simple `s[-18:-4]` would do.

With your code:

```
listingid = [img['src'] for img in soup.select('[src]')]
listingid = [s[-18:-4] for s in listingid]
```

or, in one statement:

```
listingid = [img['src'][-18:-4] for img in soup.select('[src]')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of characters is exactly the same use slicing for shorthand, if it differ I would recommend to try `split()` by pattern:

```
[i.get('src').split('_')[-1].split('.')[0] for i in soup.select('[src]')]
```

or using `regex`:

```
import re
[re.search('.*?([0-9]+)\.[a-zA-Z]+$',i.get('src')).group(1) for i in soup.select('[src]')]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<img src="img/katalog/honda-crv-4x2-2.0-at-2001_30082022103745.jpg">
<img src="img/katalog/mitsubishi-xpander-1.5-exceed-manual-2018_08072022134628.jpg">
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[i.get('src').split('_')[-1].split('.')[0] for i in soup.select('[src]')]
```

##### Output

```
['30082022103745', '08072022134628']
```